# MatLab can't modify data in place

Tags: matlab

I have issues with functions that operate in place with MatLab. I've also read Loren's blog on in-place operation on MatLab, and the example there is a bit lacking. First, let me show you a function:

```
    % a method of my_class < handle
    function obj = ip_find(obj, value)
        if value == obj.value
            return
        elseif value < obj.value
            if isa(obj.left, 'Node')
                obj = ip_find(obj.left, value);
            else
                obj = nan;
            end
        else 
            % similar to above
        end
    end
```

The function `ip_find` is an in-place operation that works as intended (to specify, `ip_find` is a method of `my_class < handle`, and returns a `my_class` object). Here is what I mean: suppose that the I'm looking for `data1` using `ip_find()`, and I set `x=ip_find(arg)`. If I then modify `x`, then `data1` is also modified, `x` is not only a copy of `data1`.

Now please take a look at this function below (`priv_delete` works as intended, `set` is a method of `matlab.mixin.SetGet`):

```
    function delete23(obj, value)
        [left, right] = neighbours(obj, value);
        lvalue=nan;rvalue=nan;

        if isa(left, 'Node_augmented')
            lvalue = left.value;
        end
        if isa(right, 'Node_augmented')
            rvalue = right.value;
        end

        % priv_delete works as intended, the issue is not here
        obj.root = priv_delete(obj.root, value);

        if ~isnan(lvalue)
            lnode = ip_find(obj.root, lvalue);
            if ~isnan(rvalue)
                rnode = ip_find(obj.root, rvalue);
                set(lnode, 'suc', rnode);  % <---- issue
            else  % then right is nan
                set(lnode, 'suc', nan);    % <---- issue
            end
        end
        if ~isnan(rvalue)
            % similar to above
        end
    end
```

The issue is with the lines where I invoke `set`. It appears to be that I'm operating on a copy of the data, instead of *directly* on the data. Thus my tests fail, as I only modified the copies! I'm not sure what is wrong, I can't seem to find the bug. I have thought of using pointers but MatLab does not even support it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you confuse the concept of “in place operation” (a function that modifies its input directly, instead of copying it first), and “handle object” (an object that points at data, so that when it’s copied, the copy points at the same data).

Where you do

```
set(lnode, 'suc', rnode);
```

you modify `lnode`, which is a local variable. You don’t write this variable to anywhere else, so at the end of the function your modified object will be deleted. Unless `lnode` is a handle object, in which case, by modifying it, you modify some global value somewhere that is also referenced by other local variables.

In MATLAB, everything is passed by value. You should always think of variables inside your function as containing copies to the data passed in. Sometimes these values are handles to data elsewhere, in which case it’ll appear as if the variable was passed by reference, but in effect you passed a copy of the handle.

A handle object is an instantiation of a handle class, a user-defined class that inherits from `handle`. All copies of such an object point to the same data (in effect share data), so modifying one copy will modify all other copies as well.

You can write a function that does in-place modifications to its input by making the output variable name the same as an input variable name, only modifying that variable (rather than assigning a new value to it), and calling this function with the same variable as input and output. For example:

```
v = ones(10);
v = f(v);

function x = f(x)
x(1) = 0;
end
```

What this does is skip the copy of the matrix `v`, which would otherwise be made inside a function that modifies its inputs. In this case the copy can be avoided because the original matrix won’t exist any more after the function call. So the in-place operation is an optimization of the interpreter, not a language feature. The final result would be identical if a copy were made (which is in fact what happened with that code prior to 2015 or whenever this optimization was introduced).

Comment: Cris, I did define `my_class` to inherit handle. When I use `ip_find` (a method of `my_class`) on the console, it worked as I intended.

Comment: I can confirm, I just checked on console. I did: `d = ip_find(w.root,-3)`, then `d.value=-10`, and my data changed.

Comment: Not just `d` (the handle?) changed, the actual data changed, I have another method of accessing the data with which I can confirm that the actual data changed.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes You are saying that `lnode` is a handle object, but `set(lnode,'suc',…)` doesn’t change the `suc` property? You either overloaded the `set` method, or you are looking at the wrong node.

Comment: @AyamGorengPedes you are talking about modifying your variable by reference, not in place.

Comment: Here's another way to look at it: Matlab `handle` classes don't give you in-place modification behavior. That's because the handle objects themselves are "pass-by-referencey", but all the primitive Matlab arrays _inside the handle object's properties_ are still regular pass-by-value/copy-on-write Matlab values. In my testing, use of handle classes or structs actually _defeats_ the Matlab engine's in-place-modification optimization (at least as of Matlab R2019b). In-place-modification only works on local variables inside workspaces, AFAICT.

Comment: And regardless, Matlab's in-place-modification optimization behavior has *no* effect on the results or output of a computation or a program's semantics (outside of some esoteric debugger behavior); it's simply an internal optimization of the execution engine to make things go faster.

Comment: @Andrew That's interesting, about handle classes defeating the optimization. Good to know!